# Does Origin support Spore?

Tags: origin, spore

I came across my old Spore account last week, and contacted EA about if it works on Origin. They asked for my verification and I gave it to them, they verified that my Spore account was valid. [The support person then simply added Spore onto my Origin account.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkPRP.png)

Later on, I've launched Spore from Origin and it asked me for my serial key. I looked at Game Info of Spore using Origin, and my key was listed there. But entering it gave me "invalid key" and live chat was unable to solve the issue.

- Is Spore still officially supported by EA?
- Does Origin officially support Spore?

I've just received a response from email support:

> I understand that you are not able to play Spore on your computer. As a gamer myself I understand how frustrating this can be. Unfortunately we cannot support the game with this type of error because the game is no longer being updated for current versions of Windows.

They offered a free game instead. But I'm simply looking to get Spore working.

Sigh. So my main question is now "How can I get my legit copy of Spore playable?"

Comment: My first instinct would be to get back to EA about it than posting it here.

Comment: @JamesJiao I think the question is still a valid question.  Maybe a slight edit is necessary - but he's essentially asking if the game is supported - not for a solution to his related problem.

Comment: @JamesJiao I just did, see edit.

Comment: The issue cannot be Win7, cuz its running fine on my rig. I don't have any addons though.

Comment: @Brant: The original question as stated is about playing Spore from Origin. It never said anything about getting the game to run on Windows 7 specifically. I don't think the quoted response changes the meaning of the question in any way.

Comment: Sounds like EA didn't reactivate your key, or something similar. Also their answer doesn't look related to the problem, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it is supported, at least as of now (April 2015). I just did a fresh install of the Mac version from my Origin account. The key that Origin gave me worked when I pasted it. The only wrinkle I had was that I had to enter the key in the original downloaded program, before applying updates and patches. There's a bug where the patched version won't launch correctly if you've never entered your key.

Comment: It is still up, you could even join the Spore servers if you use your origin credentials in-game.